# I have a statistics homework problem how to find new sample mean

Tags: statistics

A random sample of 10 bank customers is asked how frequently they make credit card purchases each month.  The resulting sample mean is x=102.5. If an 11th observation of 145 credit card transactions per month is added to the sample, what is the value of the new sample mean?

Comment: Welcome to mathematics stack exchange. Please try to show your attempt at your homework in future posts.

Answer (score 0):

Let the sum total of 10 purchases be a

$$ a = 102.5 \times 10 = 1025$$

let new mean be b

$$ b = \frac{a+145}{11}  = 106.36 $$